# How to show an alert after the file was successfully uploaded in ASP.net MVC 3

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, jsonresult

For now I am able to upload the file successfully... What I'm trying to do right now is show an alert box if the file was successfully uploaded or show an alert for the error/exception if not...

Here is my view:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "File", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
        {
        <div class="control-group">                
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
        }
```

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]   
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    try
    {
        //some code here for the upload....             

        /*In this part is my problem...Both Lines below is not showing the alert...*/
        //return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert('The calendar XML file was uploaded successfully!');" };
        //return JavaScript("alert('The calendar XML file was uploaded successfully!');");
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {   
        log.Error("HomeController::Upload()", e);
        return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "alert(\"" + e.Message + "\");" };
    }
}
```

What i would like is that my view would still remain... no redirection of page... just merely showing of that alert box for the message...Thank you! Any ideas is greatly appreciated coz i know this way of mine is not recommended... :)

Comment: How can you determine if the file is uploaded successfully without returning anything from your action ?

Comment: i have handled that in the "some code here section"... what my problem right now is how to show that alert box... (if the file was not uploaded i automatically throw an exception in the "some code section")

Comment: uncomment `return JavaScript("alert('The calendar XML file was uploaded successfully!');");` and try `$.getScript("/Controller/Action", function(){ alert('script loaded');
  });
});` in view

Comment: sorry but "return JavaScript("alert('The calendar XML file was uploaded successfully!');");" will just redirect me to a page and displaying the alert in plain html...

Comment: may be you should use string builder class `System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); string message="successfull";
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("')};");
sb.Append("</script>");             
return JavaScript(sb.ToString());   
`

Comment: sorry but i dont think returning a javascript is the right way... its just merely returning a plain html page with the script in text... hmmmm....

Comment: Try returning as `return Content(sb.ToString(),"text/javascript");`.

Comment: i hate to say this but still it doesnt work... it still returning the script as plain normal html/text

Comment: It works perfectly on my side. I dont know what was wrong with your controller action

Comment: do u mean an alert box was displayed?

Comment: can u please post your complete answer as a reply to my question...thx so much for ur effort and support

Comment: Yes. I could see an alert. Can you show me what have you written in your controller action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the right solution [here.](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm)

The link above was for showing a confirmation box before submitting the form and showing an alert for the message that was a json object returned by my controller...

```
return Json(new { isok = true, message = "Successfully uploaded the calendar XML file!" }, "application/octet-stream");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i've done to get the Alert from the controller

Here is the View Code:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("DoSomething","secure"))
{
    <input type="submit" value="get alert" />
}
```

Here is Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult DoSomething()
        {
            string message = "hai";
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
            sb.Append("alert('");
            sb.Append(message);
            sb.Append("')};");
            sb.Append("</script>");
            //return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Hello there');</script>"); //You can get the alert with this line also
            return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/javascript");
        }
```

Even there is no need of script, it directly shows alert when the `get alert` button is clicked

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Karthik! Thank you for your effort and support. I was able to find the solution I need. I just have to return a json object with a content-type of "application/octet-stream". Thx again :))

Comment: No in this case it's not working., +1 for your Effort.[See this question. The Answer has the Soln](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666122/mvc-4-fileupload-success-message)